# NGINX workers not enough

Tags: nginx, connection, curl

I'm not very familiar with nginx workers so I'll need some help here. I have two sites on one server

- http://example.com
- http://example-second.com

Second one is used to make API call through first one and receive json array. This is the scenario.

In http://example-second.com/api_call.php file I have

```
function get_curl($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
}
$url=get_curl("http://example.com/api.php?ID=foo");
```

In http://example.com/api.php

```
function get_curl_from_api($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER=> 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=> 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>2
    ));
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);   
      curl_close($curl);
      return $resp;    
}

$url=get_curl_from_api("https://thirdpartsite.com/".$_GET["ID"]);
```

From time to time I receive on `example-second` site NULL with error in log

> 32224#32224: 10 worker_connections are not enough

I know what this mean since in nginx.conf I have

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 10;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}
```

My question is how workers work exactly because why this happen from time to time? Is there some cache or keep-alive session or something? And another question is it possible to get some workaround on this without increase worker_connections? Perhaps some delay on curl function?

Comment: "worker connections are not enough" means that you're runnig out of nginx workers and is usually related to nginx (mis)config. [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265717/worker-connections-are-not-enough).  Can you explain how the PHP scripts are astarted (php-fpm?) and show respective nginx config part?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, it is `php-fpm` which nginx config part I should show? p.s. I understand what the error means.. I just don't understand how workers work.

Comment: Can you show part of nginx config which send requests to php-fpm, please?

Comment: Are you asking for the sites conf files? eg. `example.conf` and `example-second.conf`?

Comment: My first comment is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx have asynchronous event-driven architecture, single worker is processing multiple connections. `worker_connections` is maximum number of connection that worker process can open simultaneously. Not just client, but also proxy connections etc. You have this option set to very low value 10. At least you should reset it to default value 512.